# Parse Data into NSTableView

Tags: swift, nstableview

Hello fellow programmers,

First off, I am new to OSX/iOS programming and am trying to learn swift. I am fairly competent in java and wanted to teach myself something new. I am aware that the swift programming language is in it's early stages.

I have a table using the parse.com data browser. I can get the elements from that table and store them in an array. Normally, in java, I would then simply iterate over those elements and populate a JTable. Now, my question to you is...How would I go about doing this? I have tried to read the apple api and I felt my IQ dropping. I can understand the getNumberOfRows function/method however the other functions mean nothing to me. I have an NSTable in my xib file and have west the delegate and datasource to the app delegate file. How do I set the identifier so that I can start setting information.

I understand that I am not really helping but any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, tableviews with Cocoa are... complicated.

The absolute basics for getting content in the tableview is to set its datasource, which has to adopt `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol. Then you have to differentiate between a view based and a cell based tableview. In the view based you can use a view you designed in Interface Builder, the cell based are older and simpler. You understand the `numberOfRowsInTableView` function, so I proceed with the more complicated functions.

### Cell based TableVies

For cell based tableViews, the second essential function## Heading ## is

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!
```

When you just got it, it's pretty easy. As first parameter you get the tableView (only interesting if you use the same dataSource for multiple tableViews).
The second specifies the tableColumn. You can identify a column by using its identifier. You set this identifier in the InterfaceBuilder. Click on your tableview until a column is selected. Then set in the sidebar the Restoration ID.
As last parameter you get your row. You return an object of type AnyObject. I normally return a string, I don't know whether NSNumber is also valid.
A simple example implementation is the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!{
    var result = ""
           
    var columnIdentifier = tableColumn.identifier
    if columnIdentifier == "number" {
        result = "\(row+1)"
    }
    if columnIdentifier == "name" {
        result = model.persons[row].name
    }
    if columnIdentifier == "lastName" {
        result = model.persons[row].lastName
    }
    return result
}
```

When you want to set values, use

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, setObjectValue object: AnyObject!, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int)
```

Object represents the new value you should transfer to your data model.

### View based TableViews

In view based tableViews, the things lays different.

Here you have to design a custom view in a separate nib file. Then, you register the nib in your initializer.

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "Example", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forIdentifier: "Example")
```

This allows you to create instances of your view using `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`
Then you can configure your view (I like to subclasses NSView for this) and pass it back as result of

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> NSView!
```

Example implementation:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> NSView!{
    let view = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("Example", owner: self) as MyCustomView
    view.field1.stringValue = model.persons[row].name
    view.field2.stringValue = model.persons[row].lastName
    view.field3.stringValue = "\(row+1)"
    return view
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. I cannot thank you enough, it's starting to make sense. Which is more used view or cell based? Would I out the Nib in the global scope where the delegate and data source are located?

Comment: I cannot say what is more used. It just depends on. Until Yosemite, cell based table views looked old, but now that is much better.
It depends on the type of data you want to present. If it's just a simple table, take a cell based. For more complex information or an advanced formatting use a view based.

I don't understand your second question. You register your nib typically in the init of your datasource, but you can principally do it everywhere where you have access to the tableview. Just make sure that viewForTableColumn isn't called before that happened.

Comment: I am sorry, you probably think I'm a simpleton. Basically I have four arrays filled with data. One array for each table column. I simply want to iterate over these arrays and populate the table. I am truly grateful for all the support I have received in such a short time.

Comment: I remember the time, when I wanted to fill a NSTableView...
But here is everything you need. I would take a cell based tableView for this and then you use a different array depending on the columnIdentifier and return the entry on position row

Comment: This is fantastic! I now have it working. As you seem so knowledgable, what function would I use for a user electing a row within that table? I am going to mark this question as answered by yourself as this is such as detailed response. Once again thank you.

Comment: If you still need this information, I would suggest you to take a look into the NSTableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: This is mostly working. The table shows the correct number of rows, and the tableView function is being correctly called. I'm testing by println()ing the values I want to return, and they are being properly retrieved, but the table view insists that every cell should have the content "Table View Cell"

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as @EzekielElin -- where have we gone wrong?

Comment: Ok, so I resolved this issue @nhgrif. Here is the code https://github.com/ezfe/March-Intensive-Placement/blob/8085bab211628d476386e44255ea05f13d488056/March%20Intensive%20Placement/ClassTableDelegate.swift#L19-L35, essentially I made a text object and set its String value. I don't know why I needed that double !!, but it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out my issue, but it was a different fix.

Answer (score -2):

The way we do it in iOS is, In the class that is the TableView's Delegate and Datasource we implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{


    var ident = "cellIdentifier"
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ident) as UITableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: ident)
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = myTitleArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

To handle the user selecting a row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
```

}

And to tell it how many rows there are:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return myTitleArray.count
}
```

Where `myTitleArray` is your array of titles, obviously you can change that as you wish.

The way you find out what you should actually put as `var ident = "cellIdentifier"`
is the is the identifier you gave the dynamic prototype cell in the storyboard

I agree sometimes the [Apple Developer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can be confusing and often they have a [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1) which is way more helpful.

Try looking [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) for what I understand is what you want.

If your very interested in iOS programming check out [these free Stanford lectures on iTunes U](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) particularly 11, 12, and 13 talk about UITableView. They are in iOS 7 so nothing about Swift, but the only real difference in the implementation of UITableView is syntax between those languages

Comment: I would like to thank you for your detailed response. It's exactly the sort of thing I am after. However I was looking for an osx based answer. I do apologise for my inaccuracy and potentially wasting your time.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html) is the programming guide for that, sorry I should have read the question more thoroughly.