# Getting array objects into NSTableView

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I want to **catch information from an array and display it into my NSTableView.** I'm unsure what I need to do for that (I am very new to Swift and programming in general).

My table view looks like this:

[image]

**I want to get value name from my array and display it in the name table with the NSTableView**. I've found [this tutorial on Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial) but the code is very outdated and I don't want to use old things within my project which might not work anymore in newer OS versions.

It seems that I need an `[NSTableViewDataSource numberOfRows][3]` and [viewFor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1527449-tableview).

Any examples on how to do this - maybe someone made this a few weeks ago with Swift 3? :D

The information within the array will be generated by the following:

```
var devices = [Device]()
    let quantityDevices = quantityData.intValue

    for i in 0...quantityDevices-1 {

        let newDevice = Device()
        print("created new device")

        newDevice.name = titleData.stringValue + "-\(i)"
        devices.append(newDevice)
    }

    print("now we have \(devices.count) devices in our array")


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part of the code you need is the DataSource delegate functions:

```
extension ViewController : NSTableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return devices.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    // 1 - get the device for this row
    guard let device = devices[row] else {
      return nil
    }

    // 2 - configure the cell with the device data
    return nil
  }
```

There is an example [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089099/parse-data-into-nstableview) that should give a better example

Comment: Thank you for your post! I am using OS X and an NSTableView, not on iOS / UITableView - thats the matter.

Any information for this?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the tag!. Err, I'll have a quick look, I think its fairly similar

Comment: No problem, all set. I've got time! :D

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial This should give you all of the information you need... probably more. I'll udpate my answer very shortly

Comment: Thats what I mentioned above I've found earlier, didn't help me very much because it's Swift 2.2 code. To learn what it does, example code is the best for me because I can set break points and understand what it is doing.

Let me know when you're finished :D

Comment: I have updated the answer with a delegate for OSX and provided a link to a better example. I haven't done much OSX development but the principle is the same, you need to tell the tableview about the data, so it will ask you how many rows you have, so return devices.count, when it asks you to provide a row, you get the device for that row and then configure each column/view with the data specific to that device

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into it. If I have further questions, it may be better to ask in the thread you've linked?

Comment: The other thread may not be as active. if your having a specific problem create a new question and post the code and any errors you have and then people can see what you've done and what it wrong and offer guidance. This question was quite broad without seeing what tableview code you have already. I think this particular question is answered, close it or accept answer and move on. then raise any other, more specifc questions. I'll keep an eye out for them